# Angular display four elements of an array on a row

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an array of skills, unlimited number. I'm trying to display just four skills on a row.
Example: First row: Html CSS JS Java
Second row: Angular Spring C++ Python
And so on. How cand I do it?
My code is:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="skills" class="skillsColumn">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="skillsColumn">Skills
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="skillsColumn">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let skill of skills">
          {{ skill.name + " " }}
        </ng-container>
      </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: DDenis, you needn't repeat the same question several times. You can see your questions if you (click) in the link of you "avatar" -at top right of the page-. In Summary you has your recents questions.

Answer (score 1):

In your `*matCellDef`, use a template like the following:

```html
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="skillsColumn">
  <div class="skills-container" *ngFor="let skill of skills">
    <div class="skill">{{skill.name + " " }}</div>
  </div>
```

And add the following CSS

```css
.skills-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: auto;
}

.skill {
  flex: 0 0 25%
}
```

The `skill` CSS class means basically "Do no shrink content, do not grow content, make it 25% of the parent's width".

Make sure the `skillsColumn` class is wide enough to fit four long names in a row and you should be good.

*Note: If you plan on using some padding/margin in the `skill` CSS class, keep in mind that the padding/margin is computed before the `flex: 0 0 25%`. To keep 4 items per row with padding/margin, you should use `flex: 0 0 20%` or whatever percentage fits depending on your padding/margin*

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wrap the ng-container in a div and add that div a display: grid and grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%)

something like

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="skills" class="skillsColumn">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="skillsColumn">Skills
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="skillsColumn">
        <div class="grid">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let skill of skills">
            {{ skill.name + " " }}
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </mat-cell>
</ng-container>


.grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
}
```